# iOS application version number in MonkeyTalk Test result XML file

Tags: monkeytalk

I am currently testing my iOS app using MonkeyTalk, and i am trying to identify the version number of my app within the XML file that Monkeytalk generates after test.

Answer (score 0):

What you could see in the result XML file are the things that MonkeyTalk core framework does support by default. You may need to use **"Exec()"** command in your test script to achieve the goal.

As you've already known, in objective-c these 2 lines will give you the information you need:

```
NSString *versionNo = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSString *buildNo = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Here is the information about **"Exec()"** command, in both MT language and Javascript:
https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-language-reference/command-reference

Good luck! :)

P/S: For better support, you may need to post your question in MonkeyTalk forum:
https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk/forum